# Boost.Python invalid keyword argument crashing the interpreter

Tags: boost-python

I'm trying to define a class with multiple constructors methods, some of which take keyword arguments. Everything works as expected/intended until the constructor is passed a bad parameter list, in which case the interpreter dies instead of throwing an exception. Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>

class Crash {
  public:
    Crash(std::string) { }
    Crash(int, int) { }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule) {
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<Crash>("Crash", init<std::string>())
        .def(init<int, int>((arg("i") = 3)))
    ;
}
```

Output:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mymodule as mm
>>> mm.Crash("asdf")
<mymodule.Crash object at 0x00D9FB70>
>>> mm.Crash(3)
<mymodule.Crash object at 0x00D9FE10>
>>> mm.Crash(4, i=5)
<mymodule.Crash object at 0x00D9FB70>
>>> mm.Crash(i=3) # kills the interpreter
```

Putting in an invalid keyword, e.g., `Crash(blah=4)`, also kills the interpreter.

Is this a Boost.Python bug, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Boost 1.51 / Python 2.7.3 / MSVC 9.0.

Comment: Other than the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` macro argument being surrounded by quotes, everything looks fine.  I do not observe the interpreter crashing with Boost 1.53, Python 2.7.3, and gcc 4.7.2, and instead got an exception with the appropriate signature information.  [Debugging](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#debugging) may provide some additional information.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Fixed the quotes, sorry (module name was changed after the fact...). The crash occurs in function.cpp, line 189. PyTuple_GET_ITEM is applied to a PyObject* pointing to None (the key, value pair looked up for the invalid keyword), leading to undefined behaviour(?) I don't think updating boost will fix this, but I'll try anyway and get back.